# Cómo puedo eliminar algun proveedor en mi struct.?

Tags: eliminar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 4

//Esta es mi estructura con sus respectivos campos.
struct proveedor{
    
    int idProveedor;
    char nombreProveedor[20];
    char nombreProducto[20];
    int telefonoProveedor;
    char correoProveedor[20];
    
}proveedores[TAM];


int main(){
    
    int opc,i,pos,con;
    
    
    do{
        
    
        printf("\n\n1.Agregar Proveedor\n2.Consultar Proveedor\n3.Modificar Proveedor\n4.Salir");
        printf("\nEliga una opcion: ");
        scanf("%d",&opc);
        
        switch(opc){
             

 //Aquí voy a insertar los datos del proveedor. Vaya la redundancia, voy a darlos de alta.         Aunque también tendría que poner un if, para que cuando alguien quiera rellenar el arreglo en una posición ocupada, le diga que esta ocupado.


            case 1:

                
                do{
                
                
                    for(i=0; i<TAM; i++){
                    
                        printf("\n\nEn que posicion lo quieres almacenar: ");
                        scanf("%d",&pos);
                                    
                        printf("Introduzca el Id del proveedor: ");
                        scanf("%d",&proveedores[pos-1].idProveedor);
                        
                        fflush(stdin);
                        printf("Introduzca el nombre del proveedor: ");
                        gets(proveedores[pos-1].nombreProveedor);
                        
                        printf("Introduzca el nombre del producto: ");
                        gets(proveedores[pos-1].nombreProducto);
                        
                        printf("Introduzca su numero telefonico: ");
                        scanf("%d",&proveedores[pos-1].telefonoProveedor);
                    
                    
                        fflush(stdin);  
                        printf("Introduzca su correo electronico: ");
                        gets(proveedores[pos-1].correoProveedor);
                
                        printf("\n\nSu registro ha sido registrado con existo");
                        
                        printf("\n\nDesea agregar otro proveedor Si = 1, No = 0: ");
                        scanf("%d",&con);

                            for(i=0; i<TAM; i++){
                        
                                printf("\n%d. %d %s %s %d %s",i+1,proveedores[i].idProveedor,proveedores[i].nombreProveedor,proveedores[i].nombreProducto,proveedores[i].telefonoProveedor,proveedores[i].correoProveedor);
                        
                            }           
                    }
                    
            }while(con != 0);
        
        break;
        


//Aquí voy a consultar el proveedor existente, otra idea que tengo planeada hacer es hacer una búsqueda, para saber si existe dicho proveedor. 
        case 2:
            
            for(i=0; i<TAM; i++){
                
                printf("\n%d. %d %s %s %d %s",i+1,proveedores[i].idProveedor,proveedores[i].nombreProveedor,proveedores[i].nombreProducto,proveedores[i].telefonoProveedor,proveedores[i].correoProveedor);
                
            
            }
                printf("\nQue proveedor deseas consultar: ");
                scanf("%d",&pos);
                
                printf("Proveedor seleccionado: %d %s %s %d %s",proveedores[pos-1].idProveedor,proveedores[pos-1].nombreProveedor,proveedores[pos-1].nombreProducto,proveedores[pos-1].telefonoProveedor, proveedores[pos-1].correoProveedor);
            
            
        break;



        
//En este caso, podré modificar algún proveedor, si me llegará a equivocar en algo.
        case 3:
            
                
                for(i=0; i<TAM; i++){
                    
                    printf("\n%d. %d %s %s %d %s",i+1,proveedores[i].idProveedor,proveedores[i].nombreProveedor,proveedores[i].nombreProducto,proveedores[i].telefonoProveedor,proveedores[i].correoProveedor);
                    
                    
                }
                
                printf("Que proveedores deseas modificar: ");
                scanf("%d",&pos);
                
                printf("El proveedor que deseas modiciar es: \n");
                printf("%d %s %s %d %s",proveedores[pos-1].idProveedor,proveedores[pos-1].nombreProveedor,proveedores[pos-1].nombreProducto,proveedores[pos-1].telefonoProveedor,proveedores[pos-1].correoProveedor);
                
                printf("\n\nEn que posicion lo quieres almacenar: ");
                        scanf("%d",&pos);
                                    
                printf("Introduzca el Id del proveedor: ");
                scanf("%d",&proveedores[pos-1].idProveedor);
                        
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Introduzca el nombre del proveedor: ");
                gets(proveedores[pos-1].nombreProveedor);
                        
                printf("Introduzca el nombre del producto: ");
                gets(proveedores[pos-1].nombreProducto);
                        
                printf("Introduzca su numero telefonico: ");
                scanf("%d",&proveedores[pos-1].telefonoProveedor);
                        
                fflush(stdin);  
                printf("Introduzca su correo electronico: ");
                gets(proveedores[pos-1].correoProveedor);
                
                printf("\n\nSu registro ha sido modificado");
                
            
            
        break;  
    
    }   
    
    }while(opc != 4);
        
    
    

    
    //No se como eliminar el producto, es lo único que me falta
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un arreglo estático de tamaño 4 de proveedores. Al ser un arreglo tamaño estático no podes eliminar registros. Lo que si puedes hacer es reemplazar esas posiciones por otros datos o simplemente hacerles una marca para diferenciar estas posiciones de las demas.

Por ejemplo:

```
printf("\n\nQue posicion quieres eliminar?: ");
scanf("%d",&pos);
                                    
proveedores[pos-1].idProveedor = -1
```

Entonces ahora sabes que el proveedor que tiene `idProveedor` igual a -1 significa que esta eliminado y no lo tienes que mostrar.

Comment: No me sirvió, solo se modifico el ID como -1.